# No module named 'ti_image' in TI-nspire CX II python

Tags: python, ti-nspire

this is a question specific to the Ti-nspire's python library, but there isn't a tag specifically for it.

I'm trying to use its `ti_image` module, which to my knowledge should be pre-installed on the calculator like all of the other modules that work fine. However, when I try to import it with `from ti_image import *`, it gives my an import error saying there is no module named `ti_image`. Nothing in the official docs indicated that I need to download it somewhere or do something special just for this module. Is it somehow not preinstalled on my calculator? And if so, is there a way for me to install it now?

Here is the snippet of code that causes this problem:

```py
# Works fine
from ti_draw import *

# Error: No module named ti_image
from ti_image import *

img = new_image(50,50,(255,255,255))

# ... rest of program
```

Again, this is on my TI-Nspire CX II, thanks.

Comment: Hello, can you share a bit of code, and try to give us examples of how you are doing/using it in your code? It will be helpful to get more context.

Comment: The only code that I run to encounter the issue is the line `from ti_image import *`. After that, when I try to use functions like `set_pixel` that come from the module, they don't work--because python wasn't able to import them.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the module `ti_draw`, which has the function `draw_line`, so it would be something like this:

```
from ti_draw import *

def set_pixel(x, y, r, g, b):
    set_color(r, g, b)
    draw_line(x, y, x, y)

set_pixel(10, 20, 255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but `ti_draw` and `ti_image` are two separate modules. `ti_draw` works just fine for me.

Comment: ```set_pixel``` is not a built-in function, let alone a part of ```ti_image```.